# Debian umask defaulting to 0077

Tags: linux, debian, umask

I only noticed this because when I installed `tree` it noted `/usr/bin/mandb: can't search directory /usr/local/man/man1/: Permission denied`. I checked `/usr/local/man/man1` and confirmed that it's set to a restrictive `0700` permission.
I'm running Debian 11 Bullseye. All users are affected and default to a `0077` umask yet none of the common files set it to that value.
I checked

- `/etc/profile`
- `/etc/bash.bashrc`
- the user's `.profile`, `.bashrc`
- I also grepped for `umask.*77` but it didn't lead me anywhere

This seems to be a Debian default on my system but it's obviously breaking things. How do I get the default `0022` that's mentioned in the Debian docs back?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The default "umask" is set in `/etc/login.defs`. See `man 5 login.defs` for its description.

It looks like this on my machine here:

```
❯ grep -A16 '^# UMASK' /etc/login.defs
# UMASK is the default umask value for pam_umask and is used by
# useradd and newusers to set the mode of the new home directories.
# 022 is the "historical" value in Debian for UMASK
# 027, or even 077, could be considered better for privacy
# There is no One True Answer here : each sysadmin must make up his/her
# mind.
#
# If USERGROUPS_ENAB is set to "yes", that will modify this UMASK default value
# for private user groups, i. e. the uid is the same as gid, and username is
# the same as the primary group name: for these, the user permissions will be
# used as group permissions, e. g. 022 will become 002.
#
# Prefix these values with "0" to get octal, "0x" to get hexadecimal.
#
ERASECHAR       0177
KILLCHAR        025
UMASK           022
```

If this is not the issue, you should check the PAM configuration for your login service, "login" on the console or "sshd" for SSH for example, which is configured in the `/etc/pam.d/` directory. Don't forget to check the "common-*" files, too, the former ones include those bye default!